# How to calculate the frequency of a binary event (0 or 1) on a weekday basis over the last 10 years in matlab?

Tags: matlab, frequency, weekday

I have a single column Logical matrix with 0 and 1's and a single column weekday char matrix with weekday names. I want to calculate how may times I get a 1 for each weekday for the entire period of both matrices (both are about 10 years). Then the same for 0. Then Id like to visualise it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as @Daniel suggested

```
%// Random days and random 0s-1s created for sample
days ={'mon','tue','wed','tue','fri','wed','wed'}.';     %//'
A = randi([0 1],numel(days),1);

%// Concatenating to look it 'like' a table 
In = [days,num2cell(A)]

%//Obtain index of unique 'days'
[~,uIdx,idx] = unique(days);

%// as accumarray in default sums up, we count the number of ones
count = accumarray(idx,A);

%// Concatenating to see the output 'like' a table as you wanted to visualize it
out = [days(uIdx),num2cell(count)]
```

**Results:**

```
In = 

'mon'    [1]
'tue'    [1]
'wed'    [1]
'tue'    [1]
'fri'    [0]
'wed'    [0]
'wed'    [1]


out = 

'fri'    [0]
'mon'    [1]
'tue'    [2]
'wed'    [2]
```